# Cannot open display : in centos:7 contaier

Tags: docker, centos7, x11

I have container which looks like this:

```
FROM centos:7 

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/app_config
WORKDIR /tmp/app_config
COPY app/ /tmp/app_config
COPY ./app_init.sh /tmp/app_config/
…
CMD ["./app_init.sh"]
```

`app_init.sh` has this:

```
#!/bin/bash
su - appuser -c /tmp/app_config/main &
```

Now when trying to run `docker run -it app:0.1` gives me `Cannot open display :`

However, when I execute this container using

```
docker run --rm --privileged -ti -e container=docker -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup app:0.1 /usr/sbin/init
```

It asks me to login and after that I can manually run this command to startup my application: `su - appuser -c /tmp/app_config/main &`

Is there a way i can run my X11 application without running a `privileged` container?

Comment: If your application uses the X Window System, you at the very least need to bind-mount the X socket and the `.Xauthority` file into the container and set the `DISPLAY` environment variable.  The linked question describes this setup further.